# Validationsummary not showing errors generated in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

When I generate an error in the controller and return back the view, the validation summary doesn't show up. All works fine for errors generated from the view itself. How can we make the summary show up?

Here's the simplified controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditProfil(Prospect prospect)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "You have an error");

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View("Edit", prospect);

    return Json(prospect);
}
```

And the view looks like this:

```
@model Prospect

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Profil du prospect";
    Layout = null;
}

//Some javascript and CSS unrelated to validations

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    //My form controls...
}
```

Comment: *All works fine for errors generated from the view itself* Can you eloborate?

Comment: from the code above everything looks fine... I guess markup with validation errors gets rendered to the page but some javascript/css hides it -- can you check it?

Comment: @Mark Sure. If I have a validation in my model (like the required attribute), the validation summary will show my error message. If I don't use the model attribute but test the same thing in the controller, the error won't show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**edit**

the problem is a combination of

```
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "You have an error");
```

and

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

an empty string is `""` which is interperted as a property name, event thought it's an empty string. Either remove the boolean `false` from rendering the summary or pass `null` to the modelstate bag.

Comment: Don't you see he is returning view if the ModelState is not valid

Answer (score 3):

With MVC4, passing `null` to `ModelState.AddModelError` is invalid. This actually worked using:

```
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error");
```

and

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

It turned out that I had two problems.

1. I was returning the wrong view.
2. I was using an Ajax call and not updating the `div`.

The following solved it for me:

```
    <div id="results">
    @{
    using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateLookupTable", "Lookup", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "FormSuccess()", UpdateTargetId ="results" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

        // Form
    }
    </div>
```